# replace a sentence that contain special character &

Tags: awk, sed

In bash script :

I want to replace in an html file the occurrence word 'test' with this url :
url="http://www.test.com/testcom&_mc_jhc=ex_XZ-r&oh=044"

search='test'

tried sed :
`sed -i'.original' 's|'"${search}"'|'"${url}"'|g' index.html`

it works but it replaces as well all the & with 'test'

tried with awk :
`awk '{sub(/test/,'"${url}"')}1'`

But same issue.

why & in the url is also replaced by test?

Any solution ?

Comment: I've run into this problem a few times; try `sed "s|${search}|${url}|g" index.html > updated_index.html`

Comment: `&` is a special char in `sed` you need to escape it with backslash.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29613573#29613573), especially the section "Escaping a string literal for use as the replacement string in `sed`'s `s///` command". Since you're using a different delimiter (`|` instead of `/`), you'll have to adjust the pattern so it escapes that correctly.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you so much!!! you saved me lot of time, your solution works great :

Comment: If you want to use sed then see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) but personally I'd use awk but with string functions like `index()` and `substr()` instead of a regexp function like `sub()` since you seem to want to replace one literal string with another literal string rather than replace a regexp with backreference-enabled text.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer is to use this :

```
replaceEscaped=$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<<"$url") # escape it


sed -i'.original' 's|'"${search}"'|'"${replaceEscaped}"'|g' index.html
```

Comment: Since you're using `|` as a delimiter instead of `/`, you should add `|` to the list of characters to be escaped and remove `/`: `sed 's/[&|\]/\\&/g'`